# Bug in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_China 
I want to extract the cities as follows:

[image]

Following is the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener=urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_China'
ourURL=opener.open(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(ourURL)

count=1
print soup
for row in soup.findAll('table')[2].findAll('tr'):
    col= row.findAll('td')
    if(len(col)>0):
        print str(count)+"  "+col[0].a.string
        count+=1
```

Problem is that it only extracts part of the list (477 of item), whereas total is 656, is there a bug in beautifulsoap?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. When i run it these are the last outputs: 655  Zhoushan
656  Zhuji
657

Comment: @VincentBeltman strangely, are you using python 2.7, latest beautifulsoap and what os u use?

Comment: @VincentBeltman same!

Comment: You could try out requests instead of urllib2. Or lxml instead of bs4

Comment: @VincentBeltman  I have no problem with lxml (it retrieves 656), only bs4 has problem

Comment: It could be wikipedia. When I save the html, the page changes a little

Comment: Try running BeautifulSoup with a [different parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Comment: @miles82 That's help! Only BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml") with problem, other appears to be ok, including BeautifulSoupBeautifulSoup(markup, ["lxml", "xml"])